# django+uwsgi huge excessive memory usage issue

Tags: django, memory, uwsgi

I have a django+uwsgi based website. some of the tables have almost 1 million rows.

After a few website usages, the VIRT memory used the uwsgi process reaches almost 20GB...almost kill my server...

Could you someone tell what may caused this problem? is it my table rows too big? (unlikely. Pinterest has much more data). now, i had to use reload-on-as= 10024
reload-on-rss= 4800 to kill the workers every few minutes....it is painful...
any help?

Here is my uwsgi.ini file

[uwsgi]

```
chdir           = xxx
module          = xxx.wsgi
master          = true
processes       = 2
socket       =127.0.0.1:8004
chmod-socket    = 664
no-orphans = true
#limit-as=256
reload-on-as= 10024
reload-on-rss= 4800
max-requests=250
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
#chmod-socket = 777
chown-socket = www-data
# clear environment on exit
vacuum          = true
```

Comment: Virtual memory does not mean "physical memory". How much rss your processes are using ? Have you tried adding memory-report uWSGI option to see which requests allocate more memory ? Which database adapter are using ?

Comment: thanks roberto for quick reply. I know VIRT is not physical memory. but when it increases, the physical memory RSS also increases dramatically, reaching 6GB. quickly. my 32GB memory, only 180M left.

Comment: just now. I removed the reload-on-as and reload-on-rss, and observed this: VIRT is 17.8GB  RES: 7.8GB for uwsgi process...CPU is 100%. now VIRT is 19.8GB and RES 10GB. i am using the mysql.

Comment: unfortunately there is nothing that uWSGI can do (except recycling processes) to help you. You need to profile your app to understand where the problem is

Comment: what tools should be used for profiling django app?

Comment: i found two great articles on this huge memory issue of django app. share it here.http://blog.gingerlime.com/2011/django-memory-leaks-part-ii/

Comment: http://blog.gingerlime.com/2011/django-memory-leaks-part-i/  excellent explanation of django uses memory

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After some digging on stackflow and google search, here is the solution.

- read this [how django memory works and why it keeps going up](http://blog.gingerlime.com/2011/django-memory-leaks-part-i/comment-page-1/#comment-59726)
- read this [django app profiling](http://blog.gingerlime.com/2011/django-memory-leaks-part-ii/)

then I figured out the major parameter to set in uwsgi.ini is `max_request`. originally, I set it as 2000. now set it as 50. so it will respawn workers when memory goes up too much. 
Then i try to figure out which request causes huge data query results from database. I ended up finding this little line:

```
  amount=sum(x.amount for x in Project.objects.all())
```

While Project table has over 1 million complex entries.Occupying huge memory.... since I commented this out... everything runs smooth now.

So it is good to understand how the  [django query works with database]

Comment: Simply fetching so many rows will use a high amount of memory (far worse if DEBUG is True). Prefer `Project.objects.all().iterator()` if you make a unique use of the queried rows.
In your case this is far simpler: you would have spared all your memory using Django queryset aggregation methods.

Comment: If this `amount` is a Django field, not a Python property, you can aggregate and let the DB do the sum so faster than Python: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet

Answer (score 1):

(Sorry I don't have enough reputation to comment - so apologies if this answer doesn't help in your case)

I had the same issue running Django on uwsgi/gninx and uwsgi controlled via supervisor. uwsgi-supervisor process started using lots of memory and consuming 100% CPU so only option was to repeatedly restart uwsgi.

Turned out the solution was to set up logging in the uwsgi.ini file:

```
logto = /var/log/uwsgi.log
```

There is some discussion on this here: https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/296

Comment: thanks. I have added it in case it will cause similar problem.